# Hot To Make li:hover Not Move Siblings

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to enlarge my list-item borders when hovered, but when I do, it shifts the other icons down.

My thought was to use `position: absolute` on the parent and `position: relative` on the li or image, but the other list-items/images are still being affected.

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2e07Lv9y/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="social">
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/36x36"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/36x36"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/36x36"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/36x36"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/36x36"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    background-color: rgb(54, 129, 245);
    height: 75px;
}

.social {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1%;
}

img {
    border: 2px white solid;
}

li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 5px white solid;
    position: relative;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You could just add a padding on 5px to the li or you could add a 5px margin to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `outline` instead of `border`. Outlinke behaves similar to border, but it is not part of the elements dimensions.
see: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp

```
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 5px white solid;
    position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2e07Lv9y/7/

Comment: It's good practice to add the relevant code to your answer as well.  Nice use of `outline`

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a border `5px` wide when you hover.

You need to add a border 5px wide when not hover so that they are only changing the background colour.  Something along the lines of:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1%;
    border:5px solid  rgb(54, 129, 245);
}
```

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2e07Lv9y/4/)**

You may need to adjust the height, position, of the `li`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that on :hover li that display inline block, have more width including border. if you won't shifts down you need change .social width to more than 50% or place elements via text-align: right.

Answer (score 1):

Add

> padding: 5px;

to the normal li 
and

> padding: 0px;

to the li:hover